# How to run LINQ 'let' statements in parallel?

Tags: c#, plinq, let

I have code like this:

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var result = from x in list.AsParallel()
             let a = LongRunningCalc1(x)
             let b = LongRunningCalc2(x)
             select new {a, b};
```

Let's say the `LongRunningCalc` methods each take 1 second. The code above takes about 2 seconds to run, because while the list of 5 elements is operated on in parallel, the two methods called from the `let` statements are called sequentially.

However, these methods can safely be called in parallel also. They obviously need to merge back for the `select` but until then should run in parallel - the `select` should wait for them.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to use query syntax or the `let` operation, but you can write a method to perform multiple operations for each item in parallel:

```
public static ParallelQuery<TFinal> SelectAll<T, TResult1, TResult2, TFinal>(
    this ParallelQuery<T> query,
    Func<T, TResult1> selector1,
    Func<T, TResult2> selector2,
    Func<TResult1, TResult2, TFinal> resultAggregator)
{
    return query.Select(item =>
    {
        var result1 = Task.Run(() => selector1(item));
        var result2 = Task.Run(() => selector2(item));
        return resultAggregator(result1.Result, result2.Result);
    });
}
```

This would allow you to write:

```
var query = list.AsParallel()
    .SelectAll(LongRunningCalc1, 
        LongRunningCalc2, 
        (a, b) => new {a, b})
```

You can add overloads for additional parallel operations as well:

```
public static ParallelQuery<TFinal> SelectAll<T, TResult1, TResult2, TResult3, TFinal>
    (this ParallelQuery<T> query,
    Func<T, TResult1> selector1,
    Func<T, TResult2> selector2,
    Func<T, TResult3> selector3,
    Func<TResult1, TResult2, TResult3, TFinal> resultAggregator)
{
    return query.Select(item =>
    {
        var result1 = Task.Run(() => selector1(item));
        var result2 = Task.Run(() => selector2(item));
        var result3 = Task.Run(() => selector3(item));
        return resultAggregator(
            result1.Result,
            result2.Result,
            result3.Result);
    });
}
```

It's possible to write a version to handle a number of selectors not known at compile time, but to do that they all need to compute a value of the same type:

```
public static ParallelQuery<IEnumerable<TResult>> SelectAll<T, TResult>(
    this ParallelQuery<T> query,
    IEnumerable<Func<T, TResult>> selectors)
{
    return query.Select(item => selectors.AsParallel()
            .Select(selector => selector(item))
            .AsEnumerable());
}
public static ParallelQuery<IEnumerable<TResult>> SelectAll<T, TResult>(
    this ParallelQuery<T> query,
    params Func<T, TResult>[] selectors)
{
    return SelectAll(query, selectors);
}
```

Comment: This is not my expert area but dont you need to wait for the results of the tasks?

Comment: Yeh calling `.Result` waits for the Task execution. I oversimplified my sample code a little but this has put me on the right track, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using Microsoft's Reactive Framework ("Rx-Main" in NuGet).

Here it is:

```
var result =
    from x in list.ToObservable()
    from a in Observable.Start(() => LongRunningCalc1(x))
    from b in Observable.Start(() => LongRunningCalc2(x))
    select new {a, b};
```

The nice thing is that you can access the results as they are produced using the `.Subscribe(...)` method:

```
result.Subscribe(x => /* Do something with x.a and/or x.b */ );
```

Super simple!